# Very simple optimization algorithm producing a function parameter error

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

I am trying to write a program that maximizes a function, f(x). The algorithm is:

```
double maxx(double(*f)(const double &), double &a, double &b, const double tol = 1e-5)
{
    static double goldenratio = 0.618034;
    double c = b - goldenratio * (b - a);
    double d = a + goldenratio * (b - a);
    while (abs(c - d) > tol)
    {
        double fc = (*f)(c); double fd = (*f)(d);
        if (fc > fd)
        {
            b = d;
            d = c;
            c = b - goldenratio * (b - a);
        }
        else
        {
            a = c;
            c = d;
            d = a + goldenratio * (b - a);
        }
    }
    return 0.5 * (b + a);
}
```

I am getting an error when I call this function in main(). The error message is:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2572   'maxx': redefinition of default argument: parameter 1

What am I doing wrong here? I put the full code here: https://cloudup.com/cqHB_DKDIAF

Comment: Function pointers can be called directly using the normal function call syntax - `f(c)` is sufficient. Also there's not much point in taking a `double` by const reference; just pass it by value.

Comment: @T.C. Noted. Your second suggestion results in compiler errors.

Comment: [Not if done correctly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73349adc35d3ab10). You need to change both the type of the function pointer and the function that's being passed to it.

Comment: Excellent. Are there any efficiency benefits to doing this?

Comment: If the function is not inlined, it saves an indirection. For more complex functions, passing by value may help the compiler's aliasing analysis.

Comment: Why such strange [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)? It should be 1.6180339887... And 0.618034 is even far from double precision. Even float can be precise to ~7 digits. Your value is (phi - 1) or 1/phi, and the closest to it in double precision is 0.61803398874989490252573887

Comment: if the value is a constant, use `conts`, not `static`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring the default argument value in the function declaration ("prototype") on line 32, *and* in its definition on line 53.  For reasons unknown to me, the gods of C++ have decided that this is not allowed: see the following excerpt from 8.3.6/4 of the C++ 2003 standard:

> A default argument shall not be redefined by a later declaration (not even to the same value).

Note that this is from the now quite old C++ 03 standard -- but either the compiler you're using is still in that mode, or this behaviour remains unchanged in C++11, or both.

**[EDIT]** I forgot to mention how to solve the problem!  Just delete the default argument from every declaration except the first.

Comment: I am using C++11 on Visual Studio 2015. How can I circumvent this issue?

Comment: Just delete the default argument from the second declaration!

Comment: ie: remove " = 1e-5" from line 53. On sidenote could someone explain what the parameter 'double(*f)(const double &)' defines in english?

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 I would also like to understand this notation better. Does anyone have a good understanding of it?

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 `f` is a pointer to a function that takes a reference to `const double` and returns a `double`.